# Or versus OrElse within Linq expression

Tags: c#, linq

What is the difference within the following statements?

```
var results = db.Orders.Where(x => x.Status == Status.Yes || x.Status == Status.No)
```

and

```
var results = db.Orders.Where(x => x.Status == Status.Yes | x.Status == Status.No)
```

and

```
var results = db.Orders.Where(x => x.Status == Status.Yes).Where(x => x.Status == Status.No)
```

Should they produce the same same results?

Regarding speed execution, are they equivalent?

(Where `Status` is an enum)

Comment: Do they produce the same result in your tests?

Comment: I wouldn't expect the third to produce any results, unless `Status.Yes == Status.No`.

Comment: 1) is a logical or and will match if `x.status` has either value. 2) is a bitwise `or` with boolean values so amounts to the same thing. 3) is essentially a logical `and` and will never match both (unless they have the same underlying value in the enum.

Comment: This actually all depends on the ORM, however the last is just wrong and not equivalent at all.. Unless you are doing bitwise logic or you for some reason don't want short-circuiting don't use 2.... infact if you don't what the difference is, don't use 2 anyway

Comment: 1. + 2: [Logical OR operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#logical-or-operator-) vs [Conditional logical OR operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-or-operator-) 3.: is basically an "and" - how all of these are translated to SQL depends on the driver.

Comment: Really the only reason this distinction exists in LINQ is because it exists in both C# and VB.NET, and in C# it's "the default", so expression trees "need" to support it. Most other LINQ providers, including most SQL dialects, don't have short-circuiting (at least not *guaranteed*, they *may* do it as an optimization) so translating these faithfully takes some doing, and usually providers don't bother (that is, you shouldn't expect `a != 0 && b / a != 0` to never fail with a division by zero in every LINQ provider, even if regular language semantics guarantee that it won't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I raced your horses on .NET 5 and latest EF. I assumed that Yes=1 and No=2

> `var results = db.Orders.Where(x => x.Status == Status.Yes || x.Status == Status.No)`

Becomes

```
SELECT ...
FROM Orders
WHERE Status IN (1, 2)
```

> `var results = db.Orders.Where(x => x.Status == Status.Yes | x.Status == Status.No)`

Becomes

```
SELECT ...
FROM Orders
WHERE 
  (
    CASE WHEN Status = 1 THEN CAST(1 AS bit) ELSE CAST(0 AS bit) END 
    | 
    CASE WHEN Status = 2 THEN CAST(1 AS bit) ELSE CAST(0 AS bit) END 
  ) = CAST(1 AS bit)
```

> `var results = db.Orders.Where(x => x.Status == Status.Yes).Where(x => x.Status == Status.No)`

Becomes

```
SELECT ...
FROM Orders
WHERE (Status = 1 AND Status = 2)
```

<sub>(Which is clearly nonsensical, but not EF's fault..)</sub>

Make of it what you will..

Comment: As long as we're racing, it is then worth pointing out that the second option (with the `|` translated in a faithful manner) has no hope of using indexes as effectively as the first. Of course that need not mean the query actually performs worse (the first one may not use indexes effectively either, after all), so the actual answer still remains "it depends", which is not surprising. (The third option on the other hand is certainly efficient, since the optimizer knows that the `WHERE` cannot possibly select any rows and so doesn't bother reading any. :P)